# How do I create a function that would take a textfile, two logical operators for comment and blank lines?

Tags: r, if-statement, text-files

I am to construct a function named read_text_file.

It takes in an argument textFilePath that is a single character and two optional parameters withBlanks and withComments that are both single
logicals;

textFilePath is the path to the text file (or R script);
if withBlanks and withComments are set to FALSE, then read_text_file() will return the text file without blank lines (i.e. lines that contain nothing or only whitespace) and commented (i.e. lines that starts with “#”) lines respectively;

it outputs a character vector of length n where each element corresponds to its respective line of text/code.

I came up with the function below:

```
read_text_file <- function(textFilePath, withBlanks = TRUE, withComments = TRUE){
  # check that `textFilePath`: character(1)
  if(!is.character(textFilePath) | length(textFilePath) != 1){
    stop("`textFilePath` must be a character of length 1.")}
  
  if(withComments==FALSE){
    return(grep('^$', readLines(textFilePath),invert = TRUE, value = TRUE))
  }
  
  if(withBlanks==FALSE){
    return(grep('^#', readLines(textFilePath),invert = TRUE, value = TRUE))
  } 

  return(readLines(textFilePath))
}
```

The second if-statement will always be executed leaving the third if-statement unexecuted.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. In the order to enhances the chances of getting useful responses, can you explain a little more which kind of help you are looking for? I see you have included a draft code. Is it working? Which kind of error is it throwing?  Or is it about a different functionality you have not yet included?

Comment: Why would the second if-statement always be executed? If I run the code with `read_text_file("my_path.txt", withComments = TRUE, withBlanks = FALSE)` then the 1st and 2nd `if` conditions are `FALSE` but the 3rd is `TRUE`.

Comment: The function I have there didn't do what I wanted. 
I want a function that would return a textfile without comments "#", and blank lines when the arguments "withComments" and "withBlanks" are both FALSE.

Comment: Ah, I see. Answer coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend processing an imported object instead of `return`ing it immediately:

```
read_text_file <- function(textFilePath, withBlanks = TRUE, withComments = TRUE){
  # check that `textFilePath`: character(1)
  if(!is.character(textFilePath) | length(textFilePath) != 1){
    stop("`textFilePath` must be a character of length 1.")}
  

  result = readLines(textFilePath)
  if(!withComments){
    result = grep('^\\s*#\\s*', result, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
  }
  
  if(!withBlanks){
    result = grep('^\\s*$', result, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
  } 

  result
}
```

The big change is defining the `result` object that we modify as needed and then `return` at the end. This is good both because (a) it is more concise, not repeating the `readLines` command multiple times, (b) it lets you easily do 0, 1, or more data cleaning steps on `result` before returning it.

I also made some minor changes:

1. I don't use `return()` - it is only needed if you are returning something before the end of the function code, which with these modifications is not necessary.
2. You had your "comment" and "blank" regex patterns switched, I corrected that.
3. I changed `== FALSE` to `!`, which is a little safer and good practice. You could use `isFALSE()` if you want more readability.
4. I added `\\s*` into your regex patterns in a couple places which will match any amount of whitespace (including none)

Comment: Thank you Gregor. 
This actually works far better than mine but I noticed the following:
1. Commented lines that are indented were still returned. 
2. Few blank line were still returned but this time the quotes for them where much expanded like this       "                "

Comment: Sounds like you've got whitespace that needs ignoring. I'll update the regex patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I really appreciate it. Hopefully, you help me solve it all.
@Gregor Thomas

Comment: I have been able to rectify the first problem I noticed by just including two backward slashes in the grep function like this:
grep('\\#', result, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE). 

Although I am yet to solve the second problem I noticed.

Comment: Did you try with my updated regex patterns? If you need more help, you should probably ask a new question and provide a few sample lines of the file illustrating the trouble.

Comment: Wow! You know I am new here, I didn't know you updated your answer. Everything worked perfectly. Thank you so much @Gregor